# iphone simulator Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable

Tags: macos, system

The detail content as follwing:

> Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>     Expected in: /Applications/Xcode45-DP1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>    in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

**My condition**

There are three xcode versions on my mac os. I have xcode4.3.1, xcode4.5-DP1 and xcode4.6. When I first run my application, all is normal, and the audio files play. Then I changed the xcode version and ran my application, and the problem appeared.

**My solution**

I had searched many methods to try to find the reason for the problem. Such as the way shown in this [link](http://www.gulumiao.com/blog/2012/08/%E8%A7%A3%E5%86%B3gamecentergamekithelper%E6%8E%88%E6%9D%83%E6%8A%A5%E9%94%99%E7%9A%84%E9%97%AE%E9%A2%98/) and lldb command, but it didn't work.

**My conclusion**

Maybe it's the bug with loading the springboard on the simulator when I changed the xcode version, but I don't know how to revert to other xcode version.
Or it may not be the simulator. If anyone knows a solution, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using right now?

Answer (score 0):

May be I had found the solution.When I removed the xcode4.5DP and xcode 4.3.1，and restart the system ，my app can play the audio normal again.